# Iphone website overflowing by 20px horizontally

Tags: ios, css, iphone, wordpress, responsive-design

I'm making a responsive website. 
It is a wordpress website with a modified theme.

The theme has 5 stylesheets: max-479 px, max-767px,min-768px,min1024px

I already tested the website on the ipad and on the Nexus One(Android). And it works great!

However when i test it on an iphone 4S it causes a css bug on mobile safari and google chrome.
The css bug is that when viewing the site the user can still swipe sideways, even though i used the folowing css:

```
html
{
    width:100%;
padding:0;
margin:0;
    position:relative;
    overflow-x:hidden!important;
}
body
{
padding:0;
margin:0;
    max-width:100%;
    position:relative;
    overflow-x:hidden!important;
}
```

And i inserted this meta tag in the header.php

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,maximum-scale=1.0">
```

I checked if divs inside the content were overflowing in any way. But they weren't.
I am totally clueless what is left to do so it doesn't shift when the user swipes horizontally.

Link to the website: http://specialrequesthorns.com/

I appreciate you're help.

-- EDIT

Fixed the problem thanks to @ChrisHerbert and @mrbubbles. 
It seemed that the sidebar had an ul that has a width of 120%, setting it to 100% solved the problem!

Regards,

Menno van Muilwijk

Comment: Hi Menno. I think the easiest way to get help for this is to link to a live version to get a look at the bigger picture.

Comment: Do you get the same issues when you remove the two icons from the top right? I'm pretty sure the padding-right on the icons is doing something.

Comment: @mrbubbles I checked the top right icons and did display:none to test it. This doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: The `#omc-sidebar` element is causing the width issues.  If you delete it, the page doesn't overflow.

Comment: Further to @Chris Herbert's reply, the widths of 120% and 110% on .pis-ul are giving you the issues.

Comment: @mrbubbles Thank you for locating the problem! I totally forgot about the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess - have you tried using the full meta?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
```

Comment: I tried using that meta in header.php. It doesn't make a difference